# Clojure, can macros do something that couldn't be done with a function

Tags: function, clojure, functional-programming, macros, lisp

I'm learning Clojure macros, and wonder why we can't use just functions for metaprogramming.

As far as I know the difference between macro and function is that arguments of macro are not evaluated but passed as data structures and symbols as they are, whereas the return value *is* evaluated (in the place where macro is called). Macro works as a proxy between reader and evaluator, transforming the form in an arbitrary way before the evaluation takes place. Internally they may use all the language features, including functions, special forms, literals, recursion, other macros etc.

Functions are the opposite. Arguments are evaluated before the call, return value is not after return. But the mirroring nature of macros and functions makes me wonder, couldn't we as well use functions *as* macros by quoting their arguments (the form), transforming the form, evaluating it inside the function, finally returning it's value. Wouldn't this logically produce the same outcome? Of course this would be inconvenient, but theoretically, *is there equivalent function for every possible macro*?

Here is simple infix macro

```
(defmacro infix
  "translate infix notation to clojure form"
  [form]
  (list (second form) (first form) (last form)))

(infix (6 + 6)) ;-> 12
```

Here is same logic using a function

```
(defn infix-fn
  "infix using a function"
  [form]
  ((eval (second form)) (eval (first form)) (eval (last form))))

(infix-fn '(6 + 6)) ;-> 12
```

Now, is this perception generalizable to all situations, or are there some corner cases where macro couldn't be outdone? In the end, are macros just a syntactic sugar over a function call?

Comment: Notice that macros are expanded recursively during macroexpansion-time (usually before compilation) rather than run-time. The compiled code will be as if you had written the expansion by hand, so there is no performance penalty for it. Also remember that `eval` evaluates the form in a null lexical environment. `(let [x 10] (infix-fn '(x + 6)))` => `CompilerException ... Unable to resolve symbol: x`

Comment: These are good points I didn't thought of

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would help if I read the question before answering it.

Your infix function doesn't work except with literals:

```
(let [m 3, n 22] (infix-fn '(m + n))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to resolve symbol: m in this context ...
```

This is the consequence of what @jkinski noted: by the time `eval` acts, `m` is gone.

---

> Can macros do what functions cannot?

Yes. But if you can do it with a function, you generally should.

Macros are good for

- deferred evaluation;
- capturing forms;
- re-organizing syntax;

none of which a function can do.

*Deferred Evaluation*

Consider (from *Programming Clojure* by Halloway & Bedra)

```clj
(defmacro unless [test then]
  (list 'if (list 'not test) then)))
```

... a partial clone of `if-not`. Let's use it to define

```
(defn safe-div [num denom]
  (unless (zero? denom) (/ num denom)))
```

... which prevents division by zero, returning `nil`:

```
(safe-div 10 0)
=> nil
```

If we tried to define it as a function:

```
(defn unless [test then]
  (if (not test) then))
```

... then

```
(safe-div 10 0)
ArithmeticException Divide by zero ...
```

The potential result is evaluated as the `then` argument to `unless`, before the body of `unless` ignores it.

*Capturing Forms and Re-organizing Syntax*

Suppose Clojure had no `case` form. Here is a rough-and-ready substitute:

```
(defmacro my-case [expr & stuff]
  (let [thunk (fn [form] `(fn [] ~form))
        pairs (partition 2 stuff)
        default (if (-> stuff count odd?)
                  (-> stuff last thunk)
                  '(constantly nil))
        [ks vs] (apply map list pairs)
        the-map (zipmap ks (map thunk vs))]
    (list (list the-map expr default))))
```

This

- picks apart the keys (`ks`) and corresponding expressions (`vs`),
- wraps the latter as parameterless `fn` forms,
- constructs a map from the former to the latter,
- returns a form that calls the function returned by looking up the
  map.

The details are unimportant. The point is it can be done.

When Guido van Rossum proposed adding a case statement to Python, the committee turned him down. So Python has no case statement. If Rich didn't want a `case` statement, but I did, I can have one.

---

Just for fun, let's use macros to contrive a passable clone of the `if` form. This is no doubt a cliche in functional programming circles, but took me by surprise. I had thought of `if` as an irreducible primitive of lazy evaluation.

An easy way is to piggy-back on the the `my-case` macro:

```
(defmacro if-like
  ([test then] `(if-like ~test ~then nil))
  ([test then else]
   `(my-case ~test
     false ~else
     nil ~else
     ~then)))
```

This is prolix and slow, and it uses stack and loses `recur`, which gets buried in the closures. However ...

```
(defn fact [n]
  (if-like (pos? n)
    (* (fact (dec n)) n)
    1))

(map fact (range 10))
=> (1 1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320 362880)
```

... it works, more or less.

---

Please, dear reader, point out any errors in my code.

Comment: Lazy evaluation in the example could also be done by passing then as a lambda expression to the unless function. Are there some cases where even lambda won't do it?

Comment: @TuomasToivonen I think lambdas can always do it. As you know, what a function can't defer is evaluation of its arguments. You can surely always supply arguments as un-evaluated forms captured in lambdas. We could even use lambdas to create an `if` look-alike as a macro: look, ma, no special forms. In fact, I'll do that right now :).